# How to delete folders that don't contain a given file in zsh?

Tags: zsh

I'm looking for a way to delete all the folders in a given path that don't contain a given file. For example, using the following directory structure:

```
mkdir -p 1 2 3 4
touch 1/{a,b,c} 2/{b,d} 3/{a,c} 4/{a,c,d}
ls *
# directory_structure
# 1:
# a  b  c

# 2:
# b  d

# 3:
# a  c

# 4:
# a  c  d
```

I'd want to delete folders `3` and `4` because those are the ones that don't contain file `b`. What's the best way of doing that in zsh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because zsh is awesome, you can execute a command to test each file in a glob. Here you want `*(e:[ \! -e '$REPLY'/b ]:)`:

```
% tree
.
├── 1
│   ├── a
│   ├── b
│   └── c
├── 2
│   ├── b
│   └── d
├── 3
│   ├── a
│   └── c
└── 4
    ├── a
    ├── c
    └── d

4 directories, 10 files
% rm -r *(e:[ \! -e '$REPLY'/b ]:)
% tree
.
├── 1
│   ├── a
│   ├── b
│   └── c
└── 2
    ├── b
    └── d

2 directories, 5 files
```

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know about that glob qualifier. Notice you quote the command between the colons to avoid escaping the expansions: `*(e:'[ ! -e $REPLY/b ]':)`

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm not a heavy zsh user, there must be better way in zsh script.

```
for dir in 1 2 3 4 ; do
  [ -e $dir/b ] || rm -r $dir
done
```